# I want the current section title in header of the frame in beamer

Tags: beamer, headline

I tried the following but did not succeed:

```latex
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\insertsection}%Does not seem to do anything at all
%\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{...} doesnt help either

\begin{document}

\section{Calculus}
\subsection{Calculus1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Calculus1}
Calculus1
\end{frame}

\subsection{Calculus2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Calculus2}
Calculus2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An idea was to do it manually, put the `frametitle` and `framesubstitle` next to each other (maybe two "boxes" in header) insted of under each other, but I cant make it happen. with `\setbeamertemplate(frametitle}{...}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX,SE! I took a liberty and correct your question title. If I miss its meaning, please correct me.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

You can pretty much put anything between `\secname` and `\subsecname` you like:

```latex
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\section{Calculus}
\subsection{Calculus1}
\begin{frame}{\secname$\,\to\,$\subsecname}
Calculus1
\end{frame}

\subsection{Calculus2}
\begin{frame}{\secname\ – \subsecname}
Calculus2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: secname and subsecname]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to put the current section name automatically into the frame title. With the code that you presented, your main issue is, that you try to draw white text on a white background. Try to make the text in a different color and you will see, that your code actually does something:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\color{red}\insertsection}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\color{green}\insertsection}
```

[image]

Now to put the current section into the frame title, we should have a look, how the current frame title is defined and then modify it. So you are using the `Boadilla` theme, which loads `beamerthemeboadilla.sty` and from there we can see `\useoutertheme{infolines}`. However in `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty` no definition of `frametitle` occurs, so the default one from `beamerouterthemedefault.sty` is used.

Now let's modify it and write the section name with a colon in front of the section title:

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{myownframetitle}[1][left]
{
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
    \@tempdima=\textwidth%
    \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,#1,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
        \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
        \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fte#1\endcsname\fi%
        \strut\insertsection: \insertframetitle\strut\par%
        {%
            \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
            \else%
            {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
            \fi
        }%
        \vskip-1ex%
        \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Calculus}
\subsection{Calculus1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Calculus1}
Calculus1
\end{frame}

\subsection{Calculus2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Calculus2}
Calculus2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]